# How do I create an MD5 hash digest from a text file?

Tags: c#, hash, md5

Using C#, I want to create an MD5 hash of a text file. How can I accomplish this?

**Update:** Thanks to everyone for their help. I've finally settled upon the following code -

```
// Create an MD5 hash digest of a file
public string MD5HashFile(string fn)
{            
    byte[] hash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(File.ReadAllBytes(fn));
    return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "");            
}
```

Comment: These days it's better to avoid MD5 as it has known vulnerabilities https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's the routine I'm currently using.

```
    using System.Security.Cryptography;

    public string HashFile(string filePath)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            return HashFile(fs);
        }
    }

    public string HashFile( FileStream stream )
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        if( stream != null )
        {
            stream.Seek( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin );

            MD5 md5 = MD5CryptoServiceProvider.Create();
            byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash( stream );
            foreach( byte b in hash )
                sb.Append( b.ToString( "x2" ) );

            stream.Seek( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin );
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: That's perfect roufamatic. Does it return a 32 digit hex?

Comment: Just tested the function out, and it does exactly what I need - many thanks again.

Comment: If you don't need to reuse the stream you can of course remove all that code.  This used to be in a pipeline of sorts so that the stream could be hashed first, then gzipped.  Now I mostly just care about the hash, hence the shortcut.

Answer (score 11):

Short and to the point.  `filename` is your text file's name:

```
using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
{
    return BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(File.ReadAllBytes(filename))).Replace("-", "");
}
```

Comment: ToBase64String doesn't return what I want. However, BitConverter.ToString around the byte array does the trick

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved by `GetHashCode` with overloads, allowing to pass either a filePath, a StreamReader or a Stream:

```
private static string GetHashCode(string filePath, HashAlgorithm cryptoService = null)
    => GetHashCode(fStream: new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite), cryptoService);

private static string GetHashCode(StreamReader fileStreamReader, HashAlgorithm cryptoService = null)
    => GetHashCode(fileStreamReader.BaseStream, cryptoService);


/// <summary>
/// Compute hash code for file.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fStream"></param>
/// <param name="cryptoService">This can be either MD5, SHA1, SHA256, SHA384 or SHA512</param>
/// <returns>Hash string</returns>
private static string GetHashCode(Stream fStream, HashAlgorithm cryptoService = null)
{

    // create or use the instance of the crypto service provider
    // this can be either MD5, SHA1, SHA256, SHA384 or SHA512
    using (cryptoService ??= System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512.Create())
    {
        using var tmpStream = fStream;
        var hash = cryptoService.ComputeHash(tmpStream);
        var hashString = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
        return hashString.TrimEnd('=');
    }
} // method
```

**Usage:**

```
WriteLine("Default Sha512 Hash Code   : {0}", GetHashCode(FilePath));
```

**Or:**

```
WriteLine("MD5 Hash Code   : {0}", GetHashCode(FilePath, new MD5CryptoServiceProvider()));
WriteLine("SHA1 Hash Code  : {0}", GetHashCode(FilePath, new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider()));
WriteLine("SHA256 Hash Code: {0}", GetHashCode(FilePath, new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider()));
WriteLine("SHA384 Hash Code: {0}", GetHashCode(FilePath, new SHA384CryptoServiceProvider()));
WriteLine("SHA512 Hash Code: {0}", GetHashCode(FilePath, new SHA512CryptoServiceProvider()));
```

Comment: Good solution! I suggest a little improvement: Make the 2nd parameter nullable i.e. `HashAlgorithm cryptoService = null`  and then add a default provider like so: `using (cryptoService ??= System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512.Create())` - or if you prefer, you can use MD5 too (but I would not recommend it). This will simplify usage while keeping maximum flexibility (you are still able to add the provider of your choice).

Comment: Hint (for those who need it): In case you need a StreamReader (fileStreamReader) instead of a filepath as a parameter, you can create an overload of this function where you do like `using var fileStream = fileStreamReader.BaseStream;`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a .NET Standard version that doesn't require reading the entire file into memory:

```
    private byte[] CalculateMD5OfFile(FileInfo targetFile)
    {
        byte[] hashBytes = null;
        using (var hashcalc = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
        {
            using (FileStream inf = targetFile.OpenRead())
                hashcalc.ComputeHash(inf);
            hashBytes = hashcalc.Hash;
        }
        return hashBytes;
    }
```

You can convert the byte[] array into a string using the methods shown above.  Also: You can change "MD5" in the third line to SHA1, SHA256, etc. to calculate other hashes.