# Hash of source codes at compile time in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, hash, compilation

Having a server that other devs use, I currently log the version of the dll they use. I do that by having the client that use Reflection to retrieve its version:

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

It's nice, but since it come from dev that uses TFS and do themself the build, I can not see if they have the latest version of the sources. Is there a trick, like a compilation tag, that would easily allow a hash of the generating source code?

Note: I have try to send the [MD5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150455/how-do-i-create-an-md5-hash-digest-from-a-text-file-with-c) of the dll (using assembly.Location), but it is useless since the hash value changes between 2 compilations (I suppose there is some compilation timestamp inside the generated dll).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem there is no easy way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is most collaboraton issue then a coding.
In the moment that you find out that the version is old one.notify them about it. 
If the *real* version is not old one, that means that developers before making buold did not increment the version ID, which is mistake.

In other words, ordanize it among people, and not relly on these kind of tools (if there is any). You trying to create a complicated tool, that will help you avoid mistakes, but humans will find a way to make them again.

So it's better to create solid relation structure among you, imo.

Comment: I may be not clear: I would like to know if these kind of tools exists or not. It exists simple tools like #warning, //TODO or AssemblyVersion("1.0.*"). I would like to be aware if there a #SourceFileHash that exists...

Answer (score 0):

Create a tool on pre build event to hash/last-write-time your code files.

Write the result to a cs file or a embedded resource file.

The result file must exclude in above action.

For prevent skip build (up-to-date) feature not work,Compare the file before write.

And if youre opening the file in IDE will get a prompt `changed from out side' when build.